# Show post titles within Wordpress bootstrap Dropdown menu

Tags: menus, walker

I created custom bootstrap navwalker class for my wordpress theme all things work correctly i has this code below within `function start_el(){}`

When i put `<h2>Hellow World!</h2>` within `$item_output` the dropdwon menu show the `Hellow World!` four times in four column

But when i want put the `the_title()` wordpress function within `$item_output` like this `<h2>'.the_title().'</h2>` Show me the `Hello World!` post title above the main menu items, not within the dropdown menu

How i can solve this problem?

```
if (!empty($item->divideto_4)) {
    $col = 3;
    $divide_to = 12 / $col; //4

    for ($i=0; $i<$divide_to; $i++) {
        $item_output .= '<div class="col-sm-'.$col.'"><h2>Hellow World!</h2></div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Note the difference between `the_*`  and `get_*` core functions, is like echo vs return (in most cases).

Comment: but i have problem the above code only show the latest post means don't show the latest four posts duplicate last post four times

Comment: Can you post more of your code?  E.g. the whole start_el() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for our reply i solved my problem i used Wordpress loop query for showing last fout posts in four column as below

```
if (!empty($item->divideto_4)) {
    $col = 3;
    $divide_to = 12 / $col; //4

    $my_query = "showposts = ".$divide_to; 
    $my_query = new WP_Query($my_query);
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
        $item_output .= '<div class="col-sm-'.$col.'">';
        $item_output .= get_the_title();
        $item_output .= '</div>';
    endwhile;*/
    $YPE_col_content->YPE_lastposts();
}
```